# pdo insert into access don't work

Tags: php, ms-access, pdo

basically here's my php pdo insert code

```
$dbName = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/web/admin/mindb1.mdb";
//$dbName = "mindb1.mdb";
if (!file_exists($dbName)) {
    die("Could not find database file.");
}
$db = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Uid=; Pwd=;");

$sql  = "INSERT INTO Anggota (`Tarikh Anggota`, `No Kp`, `No Kp Lain`) VALUES ('13/03/1970', 'b111111', 'b111111')";
$db->query($sql);
```

but it seems nothing is being inserted. and not any error message we returned. but running select query like below works just fine

```
$sql  = "SELECT ID, `Tarikh`, `NoKp`, `Nama`  FROM Anggota order by ID";

$result = $db->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $id        = $row["ID"];
    $tarikhAnggota = $row["Tarikh"];
    $noKp       = $row["NoKp"];
    echo "id: ".$id." tarikhAnggota: ".$tarikhAnggota." noKp: ".$noKp."<Br>";
}
```

Comment: [Setup the PDO connection to throw exceptions.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: emmm how do i do that @PeeHaa

Comment: How do you do what? Read the manual page I just linked? I'm afraid  "how to read" is out of the scope of this site.

Comment: ooppss sorry didn't notice your comment is actually a link.. :D

Comment: thanks a lot @PeeHaa the exceptions thrown really give me good indication on what went wrong at the first place